# How to get rotation around plane different than XY in Android?

Tags: android, android-sensors

getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()

retrieves values like

```
Surface_ROTATION_0, 
Surface_ROTATION_90, 
Surface_ROTATION_180, 
Surface_ROTATION_270
```

and so on, and that's around XY plane I guess, Am i right? What if I want to know the rotation in the XZ plane or YZ plane?

What I'm trying to achieve is, for example, if I need to calculate if a runner is stopping (and I can't use the GPS) where the runner can have the cellphone in different positions, I must know which axle is the one parallel to the floor in order to check on those values if there is any deceleration and is not that the cellphone is just "jumping" with the runner.

Thanks in advance. Guillermo.